# Selecting Elements With a Specified Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a bunch of elements containing the tag "a" and the class "pointer", however, I want to select all the elements containing the tag "a", class "pointer", and a title of "Average". The closest I've came to achieving that is with this code: 
     document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer");
but even that code selects different elements with the title such as "Sum" and
"Name". So my question is, how do I select all the elements with this outerHtml:

```
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">225.42</a>
```

Comment: Would this not work? `document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']")`

Comment: using jquery like this way `$( "a.pointer[title='Average']" )`

Comment: There's no need jQuery in this situation, the jQuery selector compiles down to a query selector anyway.

Comment: @andrew196 - That worked, thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad I could help @Omega Just submitted a question if you could mark it as complete that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query Selector attribute pattern like so:

`document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']")`

Answer (score 0):

### Query Selector and magic

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.pointer[title="Average"]')
```

Let's break down how this works. `querySelectorAll` returns a list of `nodes`/`elements`.

`a` is the tag of the element
`pointer` is the class of the element
`[title="Average"]` says to look for an element with the attribute `title` with a value equal to `"Average"`

By placing these queries next to each other it tells the `querySelectorAll` method to look for an element that embodies all those qualities.